# Consolidating balances from multiple addresses in a private manner

Tags: mixers, tornado-cash

I have a large amount of Ethereum addresses that all have random amounts of Ether in them. I'd like to consolidate these into one address now, for ease of use. I was intending to use Tornado Cash to break the link between the original Ether and the Ether in the final consolidated address.

So far, though, it seems like to do this, I'll have to first send a transaction from each address to a new address that would hold the consolidated funds; then from here send the total in a single transaction to Tornado Cash, and withdraw my new, cleaned Ether to another address. However, this would reveal both my total Ethereum balance as well as the list of original addresses, to any observer, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

I'm wondering if there is any way to deposit Ether, from multiple different addresses, directly to a decentralized mixer contract like Tornado Cash, and have it credit my new address directly. Ideally, a mixer contract that allows me to choose the recipient address right when making a new deposit.

Tornado Cash Nova seems to be a little closer to what I want, but it seems to require that I first deposit it to a shielded balance tied to the original address, and then transfer to a the shielded balance of the new Ether address. Essentially, 2x the amount of transactions. With the very large number of addresses I'm starting with, the fees unfortunately become prohibitively expensive if I had to double the number of transactions.

Comment: isn't there a minimum for using Tornado Cash like 10 ether, requiring each of the wallets to consolidate to have that minimum?